# How to use subquery with linked database

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query returns the spriden_id of 820240014 as expected. This will be used as a subquery below.

```
select spriden_id 
from spriden 
where spriden_pidm = 279355 
and spriden_change_ind is null;
```

The following query returns four rows from the DAP_AUDIT_DTL table when hard-coding DAP_STU_ID to '820240014'.

```
select * 
from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST 
where DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID = '820240014';
```

Using the same query as above except with a subquery. This query returns no rows from the DAP_AUDIT_DTL table even though the subquery returns 820240014. Why doesn't this query return values just as the hard-coded query?

```
select * 
from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST 
where DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID = 
(select spriden_id from spriden where spriden_pidm = 279355 
and spriden_change_ind is null);
```

The data type of SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID is VARCHAR2.
The data type of DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID is CHAR(10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `IN` when comparing to a result set which returns multiple rows:

```
select *
  from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST 
  where DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID IN (select spriden_id
                                                from spriden
                                                where spriden_pidm = 279355 and
                                                      spriden_change_ind is null)
```

I'm rather surprised the original version didn't raise an exception.

### EDIT

Well, it looks like my initial reasoning was sound - wrong, but sound. :-)

The actual problem is that you're comparing a value stored in a CHAR field which is one character shorter than the defined length of the field to a value in a VARCHAR2 field. CHAR fields have the property that all the values stored in the field are **padded on the right with spaces** so that they are as long as the defined length of the field. In this case, the value stored in `DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID` is not `'820240014'`, it's `'820240014 '` - in other words, there's an extra space added to the end of the "visible" value to make it ten characters long. `SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID` is a VARCHAR2 field so only the specified characters - in this case '820240014' - are stored and retrieved. But when you compare the nine-character value '820240014' to the ten character value ''820240014 ' they come up as unequal.

Now, interestingly, if `SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID` was defined as `CHAR(20)` and contained the value `'820240014           '`, it would **compare as being equal** to the CHAR(10) value `'820240014 '`.

I really hope this is a university exercise, because if you're having to deal with this in a production environment - well, may Cthulhu help you. :-)

Happily, there *is* a (reasonably easy) way to handle this. If you include a specific cast of the value in SPRIDEN_ID to CHAR(10) your initial query should work:

```
select *
  from DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL@LINKDWTEST 
  where DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID IN (select CAST(spriden_id AS CHAR(10))
                                                from spriden
                                                where spriden_pidm = 279355 and
                                                      spriden_change_ind is null)
```

I suppose you could also choose to cast `DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID` to VARCHAR2(10) if you wanted to. Try it out and see what you prefer.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6598a62abeb52680ec6cc87198ad5341)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the query using IN also returns no rows. The subquery returns a single row. The primary query should return four rows.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and include the data types of `SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID` and `DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID`.Thanks.

Comment: The CAST does work, thank you!. I learned something about the CHAR data type. I also discovered that TRIM appears to work: TRIM(DWSCHEMA.DAP_AUDIT_DTL.DAP_STU_ID)